# How to pull data from a related model in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, many-to-many, relationship

So, I have two applications that I want to link together in a many-to-many relationship in my project.

The **first** application is described by the following model.

**model.py:**

```
class ChannelCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class Channel(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ChannelCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.category, self.name)
```

The **second** application is described by the following model

```
class Tariff(models.Model):
    channels_list = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, blank=True, db_index=True, symmetrical=False)

def __str__(self):
     return '%s' % self.name

def get_channels_categories(self):
    return ([str(p.category) for p in self.channels_list.all()])

def get_channels_objects(self):
    return ([str(p.name) for p in self.channels_list.all()])
```

Now what do I want to do? Suppose that the tariff object contains **4 channels**, which have **different categories**, and we get approximately the following picture: tariff A has **4 channels** from **2 different channel categories**, for example, the "mega" tariff has

> ['ChannelCategory_1: Channel_1', 'ChannelCategory_1: Channel_3',
> 'ChannelCategory_2: Channel_2', 'ChannelCategory_2: Channel_4']

I do not understand how to display information on the interface correctly. I need to get this kind of information on my template:

> ['ChannelCategory_1: 'Channel_1', 'Channel_3'']
>
> ['ChannelCategory_2: 'Channel_2', 'Channel_4'']

I will be glad for any help, thanks in advance!

**UPDATED**

Why 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'channels_list' in?

```
tariff = Tariff.objects.prefetch_related('channels_list')
category_channel_dict = defaultdict(list)
for channel in tariff.channels_list.all():
     category_channel_dict[channel.category.name].append(channel.name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked. I don't know how it looks nice or not, but inside in the **class Tariff**, you need to describe the function **get_channels**:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_channels(self):
channels = list(str(p).split(':') for p in self.channels_list.all())
channel_list = []
for category, name in groupby(channels, lambda x: x[0]):
    channels_list_by_group = ";".join([channel[1] for channel in name])
    channels_list_by_category = (category + ":" + channels_list_by_group + ".")
    print(channels_list_by_category)
    channel_list.append(channels_list_by_category)
return ''.join(channel_list)
```

Thus, we will get the following channel_list (an example of what is pulled from my database processed by this function):

> **ChannelCategory_1**: ChannelName_1; ChannelName_2;  ChannelName_3; ChannelName_4.
>
> **ChannelCategory_2**: ChannelName_5; ChannelName_6.
>
> **ChannelCategory_3**: ChannelName_6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tariff = Tariff.objects.prefetch_related('channels_list').filter(id=1)
category_channel_dict = defaultdict(list)

for channel in tariff.channels_list.all():
    category_channel_dict[channel.category.name].append(channel.name)

OUTPUT:
{
    'category_1': ['Channel1', 'Channel2'],
    'category_2': ['Channel1', 'Channel2']
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. No information is displayed. Empty list :(

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code that print it? Wich part of code didn't work? In my code I create a dictionary and then you should print dict as you wish.

Comment: Yes, of course, now I will try to state. I will now correct my question and indicate what you want, with a note that this is your proposal to resolve this issue.

Comment: @EchoFoe of course it didn't work as you write if statement, dict at first is always empty. I didn't write so. And you need to print out: category_channel_dict

Comment: I did everything according to the instructions and displayed information print(category_channel_dict) => defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})

Comment: I exclude the construct to test the condition "if category_channel_dict" and still get the same thing...

Comment: @EchoFoe can't help you. Try to debug it and print every line or hire for paid consultation

Comment: I went back to this question and checked every line. As a result, it does not work for channels_list in a loop for channel in tariff.channels_list.all(). Why can this happen? I corrected my question and removed unnecessary information. There is a screenshot of the debug.